# HTML/CSS How to correct overlap two list elements?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying now for hours to fix a issue in my code.

If the Window size of the browser gets changed, the black border does not match up with the gray border,  but it should. The gray border should should jump into the next line if it is now visible as a whole.

Any idea how I can fix this?

```css
.ul_images {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.li_image{
 display: inline-block;
}

.a_image {
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 250px;
 width: 250px;
 border: 4px solid #000;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 10px 10px;
}

.a_image_span {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: #E6E6E6;
}

.li_image_background {
 opacity: .3;
 filter: Alpha(opacity=30);
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <ul class="ul_images">
  <li class="li_image li_image_background"><a class="a_image" style="background-image: url('background.jpg');" href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="li_image"><a class="a_image a_image_backgroundsize" style="background-image: url('overlay.png');" href="#"><span class="a_image_span">text here</span></a></li>
  
  <li class="li_image li_image_background"><a class="a_image" style="background-image: url('background.jpg');" href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="li_image"><a class="a_image a_image_backgroundsize" style="background-image: url('overlay.png');" href="#"><span class="a_image_span">text here</span></a></li>
  
  <li class="li_image li_image_background"><a class="a_image" style="background-image: url('background.jpg');" href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="li_image"><a class="a_image a_image_backgroundsize" style="background-image: url('overlay.png');" href="#"><span class="a_image_span">text here</span></a></li>
  
  <li class="li_image li_image_background"><a class="a_image" style="background-image: url('background.jpg');" href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="li_image"><a class="a_image a_image_backgroundsize" style="background-image: url('overlay.png');" href="#"><span class="a_image_span">text here</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement I have placed first Gray Box over Black box. Please find fiddle link for same 
`<ul class="ul_images"> /* Your Code */ ..</ul>` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gh9skt78/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I want to overlap the black border and the gray border, without the position absolute those borders wont overlap.

Comment: Thanks for reply...I have edited my answer as per your requirement. I have placed first gray border box with the black border box. Please find link for same.